# Converting PJL/PCL to pdf

Tags: pdf, printer, ghostscript, postscript, pcl

I have a non-readable PJL file, which I try to convert into something human-readable (e.g. pdf). The PJL commands are as follows (followed by the actual print-job):

```
%-12345X@PJL JOB NAME = "{**censored-filename**}.PDF"
@PJL COMMENT NOTIFICATION = "0x00"
@PJL SET AUTHENTICATIONUSERNAME = ""
@PJL SET AUTHENTICATIONPASSWORD = ""
@PJL SET JOBNAME = "{**censored-filename**}.PDF"
@PJL SET DATE = "2010/12/17"
@PJL SET TIME = "07:38:10"
@PJL SET JOBOFFSET = OFF
@PJL SET COPIES = 1
@PJL SET QTY = 1
@PJL SET FRONTCOVERPRINT = OFF
@PJL SET BACKCOVERPRINT = OFF
@PJL SET SLIPSHEETPRINT = OFF
@PJL SET PERFECTBIND = OFF
@PJL SET RINGBINDMODE = OFF
@PJL SET SEPARATIONSHEETMODE = OFF
@PJL SET IMAGEDIRECTION = NORMAL
@PJL SET HOSTCHARSET = "iso-8859-1"
@PJL SET DISPCHARSET = "iso-8859-1"
@PJL SET HOSTPRINTERNAME = "Booklet Printer"
@PJL SET MEMORYSIZE = 512
@PJL SET AUTOTRAYCHANGE = ON
@PJL SET TABPOSITION = OFF
@PJL SET TABSTOCKSHIFTPRINT = OFF
@PJL SET STAPLE = BOOKLET
@PJL SET PUNCH = OFF
@PJL SET FOLD = OFF
@PJL SET USERID = "?"
@PJL SET USERCODE = ""
@PJL COMMENT OTHER = "a200150007d024"
@PJL SET PRINTINFO = "DUPLEX_NUP=00000800/SCALING=3/OTHER=00000004"
@PJL SET HOSTNAME = "PRINTSERVER-HP"
@PJL SET HOSTLOGINNAME = "Print Server"
@PJL SET HOSTPORTNAME = "192.168.0.17"
@PJL SET TRACKID = "AUnloAAAVkTzFXg"
@PJL SET PAPERFEEDADJUST = ON
@PJL SET PAPERERRORCHECK = OFF
@PJL SET TRAY = ALL
@PJL SET MEDIATYPE = PLAINORRECYCLED
@PJL SET OUTBIN = FINISHERSHIFT
@PJL SET PAPERFACE = DOWN
@PJL SET WHITEPAPERSUPPRESS = OFF
@PJL SET DRAWLINEBOLD = OFF
@PJL SET SMOOTHING = ON
@PJL SET ECONOMODE = OFF
@PJL SET QUALITYMODE = STANDARD
@PJL SET DATAMODE = GRAYSCALE
@PJL SET FIRSTPAGEORDER = ON
@PJL SET MIXEDDIRROTATION = OFF
@PJL SET DUPLEX = ON
@PJL SET BINDING = LEFT
@PJL SET PAGESEPARATION = OFF
@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = RPCS
\F0RPCS driver post process version 4.10.9.0\FF     \00\00\00\00\004%-12345X@PJL SET APLPAGELAYOUT = LANDSCAPE
@PJL SET PAPER = JISB4
@PJL SET APLPAGESIZE = JISB4
@PJL SET RESOLUTION = 600
@PJL SET BITSPERDOT = 1
@PJL SET PAGEORIGINX = 100
@PJL SET PAGEORIGINY = 100
@PJL SET ROTATE = RIGHT
@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = RPCS
```

I also tried what was proposed here: [Printer Job Language --> PDF](https://superuser.com/questions/791596/printer-job-language-pdf) with no luck. Any solution Linux or Windows will be accepted....

Comment: PJL commands are used to change printer settings (as you can see by reading the PJL). They do not print any data. The actual print file is on the first (and fifth) line: **censored-filename**}.PDF.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I dont have the file anymore. But the actual print-job is appended after the header I posted in the question. It looks similar to (suppose binary): `nC�6tC�QoC��hC��eC��rCzOmCy�uCy�cCz�hCz.lCzFiCz\kCy�eCz�hCz�iCzm]eC��DyC�u,C��lC��oC��vC�iC�&nC�RgC��tC`      From what I've seen the data is stored in [RPCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refined_Printing_Command_Stream). The big question is how to convert that back into something human-readable?

Comment: The file is a total of 13MB, so the data is definitely in there. From what I understand some PJL/RPCS vector format.

Comment: If you have access to a Ricoh printer, try sending the file to it, without the PJL. I do not think there is any other way to make it "readable".